# Trying to Install MariaDB with Default User and Password using Inno Setup

Tags: mariadb, inno-setup

I'm trying to create an installer for my application that allows you to choose between MySQL or MariaDB because there are many other applications that use MySQL and modify the user and password by default making it unable to connect to the database so that this does not affect me I decided to add the database engine MariaDB and if there was an application that uses MySQL can put the port 3307 with a user and password that does not affect in anything to others.

I tried to put the following lines in the Setup.iss

```
[Tasks]
Name: "MariaDB"; Description: "{cm:MariaDB}"; GroupDescription: "cm:dbOnly}";  Flags: exclusive unchecked; Components: full;
[Files]
Source: "{#InstallersDir}MariaDB\mariadb-10.4.6-winx64.msi"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: ignoreversion nocompression; Components: full; Tasks:MariaDB
[Run]
Filename: msiexec.exe; Check: not InstalledApplication('MariaDB','10.4'); Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\mariadb-10.4.6-winx64.msi"" SERVICENAME=G2DatabaseService DATADIR=""{pf}\MariaDB\MariaDB 10.4\data"" PORT=3307 BUFFERPOOLSIZE=2Gb ALLOWREMOTEROOTACCESS=1 /passive"; WorkingDir:{app}; StatusMsg:"{cm:waitDatabase}" ; Flags: runhidden ;Components: full;BeforeInstall: UpdateProgress(91); AfterInstall: UpdateProgress(95); Tasks:MariaDB;
```

I expected to create a default myUser user with myPassword and on port 3307. And only the port applies

Comment: Setting parameters in a .bat file and setting parameters adapted to Inno-Setup is different! To embed a double-quote character inside a quoted value, use two consecutive double-quote characters. Next is only one not working: SERVICENAME=G2DatabaseService correct ""SERVICENAME=G2DatabaseService"" ! Just look at inno setup help !

Answer (score 1):

This maybe be problem with MariaDB not Inno Setup.

The easiest way how to debug similar issues is to write a **.bat** file with command(s) and parameter(s) and when everything is working correctly then simply put it into Inno Setup script.

Comment: I tried what you said and although it works with the batch file and even with an SQL run from console but not with InnoSetup `[RUN] Filename: {pf64}\MariaDB 10.4\bin\Mysql.exe; Parameters: "-u root -proot --port=3307 < {tmp}\MariaDB\createUser.sql"; WorkingDir:{app}; StatusMsg:"{cm:waitDatabase}" ; Flags: runhidden ;Components: full;`

Comment: Did you follow this guide? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installing-mariadb-msi-packages-on-windows/ It says you youd pass parameters with full name like Parameters: "PASSWORD=root" ...

Comment: If nothing works you can always run your .bat file directly from Inno Setup.